# Can I get my Xbox 360 to run games from my laptop?

Tags: xbox-360, pc

I wanted to know if it is possible to connect my Xbox 360 to my laptop in a way that my Xbox is running my games from my PC.

Basically, I want my Xbox 360 to run my laptop games because my laptop is bad.

Answer (score 7):

There are no ways to connect a laptop up to an Xbox 360 and do what you are looking for.  The two devices cannot interface with one another in such a way.